# calculating standard tensor products

Tags: tensor-products

How does one show $\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/gcd(a,b)\mathbb{Z}$?
Here $a$ and $b$ are positive integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Consider the map: $$\mathbb Z\cong \mathbb Z\otimes \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/a\mathbb Z\otimes \mathbb Z/b\mathbb Z$$

Show that it is onto and that its kernel is $\gcd(a,b)\mathbb Z$

Comment: ahhhh thankyou..